# Intermittently Partially retrieved LINQ to SQL records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, azure-sql-database

I have a worker role that does a whole bunch of backend processing for our app.  I'm retrieving records with LINQ to SQL from our SQL Azure database.  However, intermittently the objects I'm retrieving are partially populated with data. The object will have the id(int auto increment), foreign key (uniqueidentifier), createdate (datetime) populated but the NVARCHAR fields will be null.

I have tried the following LINQ expressions.

```
return (from showing in DB.Showings
                    where showing.eGUID == eGUID
                    select showing).FirstOrDefault();
```

and its simpler cousin

```
DB.Agents.SingleOrDefault(a => aGuid == a.aGUID);
```

I have not experienced this in other parts of the application but I will admit that DB is the largest dataContext I have created in the app.
Any thoughts would be appreciated as I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Are those varchar fields marked as lazy-load?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Would VARCHAR strings lazy-load?

Comment: if marked as such in the model, yes. Check your model - there should be an option for this. In DBML (the xml) it  is the `@IsDelayLoaded` option.